# Evans book and hilbert sobolev space valued functions

Tags: sobolev-spaces

Hi in  Evans  book I found that  The space $C^0\left([0, T] ; V\right)$ is the space  of continuous functions from $[0, T]$ with values in $V$ is a Banach space for its natural norm
$$
\|f\|_{C^0([0, T] ; V)}=\max _{t \in[0, T]}\|f(t)\|_V .
$$

but in brezis book he considers the space  $C^{0}\left([0, \infty[ ; V\right)$ and  $L^{p}([0, \infty[ ; V)$   can we define these spaces  and there  norms in the same way if we have $T=\infty$ ?
Thanks

Answer (score 3):

The space $C^0([0, \infty[; V)$ with the supremum “norm” is not a normed space, not even if $V = \mathbb R$. The problem is that unbounded functions would have an infinitely large “norm”. However, you can consider an analogous norm on the set of continuous and *bouded* functions from $[0, \infty)$ to $V$.

I am not sure I understand your question regarding $L^P([0, \infty[; V)$ but here the norms are defined similarly as for finite time intervals. You can even start with any measure space. See [the Wikipedia page for Bochner spaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bochner_space), for instance.

Comment: Just to clarify, the key point is that $[0,T]$ is compact and $[0,\infty[$ is not. Continuous functions on a compact domain are necessarily bounded and hence have finite norm.

Comment: @keba ,@whpowell96 ,thank you for your answers, my problem is that i want to show that a function f belongs to  $C^0([0, \infty[; V)$ but i dont see how to do that?

Comment: Well, that depends on the function of course. The best general advice I can give is to follow the definition of (say, sequential) continuity. I guess it make sense to open another question where you describe your concrete example and what you attempted to do.